# Wordpress - Password protecting page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to password protect a page so only users with access can download the contents of the page. Preferably, i want to do this by having a user complete a form with their desired password and once the form is received via email, i will create a new user via Wordpress using the details they provided in the form.

I'd then like to use the Wordpress in-built password protect function or similar; only allow users access that have a password that matches as per the new user i just created in the Wordpress back-end.

I know it's possible, i just don't know how to go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask your question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com , not on SO

Comment: This Q needs improvement here or at WPSE: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Everything about WP password page protection can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection OR you can search for plugins on Google :)